# How to force creating a new Symfony application for a specific PHP version?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I want to generate a Symfony application which can be compatible with PHP version up to 7.4.22.

On my local machine, PHP version is 8.0.2 but on the hosting is 7.4.22.

Symfony application is generated from local machine using standard composer command

```
 composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name
```

I look over `create-project` arguments to see if I could add some constrains but none seems to be useful.(or didn't figure out)

If try to upload to host the project I get this when trying to install it:

> Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.0.0". You are running 7.4.22.

Need just a default empty project to check something on hosting.

I do not want to alter local PHP and doing the same thing on hosting could be troublesome.

Comment: Also, it would be easier to work with the **same** version on both systems. Everything else will only cause trouble

Comment: yes, it have but also do not want to modify from there

Comment: `"require": { "php": ">=7.2.5"` , but this json is also generated by `create-project`. So thought that on first command could add additional arguments ?

Comment: no, just generate standard application

Comment: @NicoHaase Thx. for all comments but what more detalis you needed ? I clearly state what I was trying and not working. (better said did not try anything else rather then generate standard application, upload on host and see the errors). My question reformulate is if there are any workaround with out changing local php_version. Still meantime could try some more things ...

Comment: @NicoHaase  Maybe it's just easier to add similar version on local machine and generate the application. I will point the hint if post.

Comment: Well, it could be interesting to see which packages got installed (any blocking PHP 8 to run? - you could share your `composer.json` for this), how you deployed your application (simply copying from your local machine, or a proper deployment process that maybe also ran `composer install` with any other PHP version?)

Comment: Also, if you just want to "check" something, why not run `composer create-project` directly on the server?

Comment: @NicoHaase , for deployment just ftp-copy and modify the path for `index.php`. It's troubleshooting to use `console` on hosting. (better imagine that development will be on local machine and port on host). I could share `json` if it will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name` in an example project using PHP 8 installs `psr/cache` in v2 and `psr/link` in v1.1.1. These package versions require PHP 8, and they will not work using any older version of PHP.

To avoid this, just don't run `composer create-project` with any later version than the one you want to use on your production system (as usually, running it with a lower PHP version than on production yields a set of packages that is compatible with the production system, while the chance is lower the other way around).

Otherwise, check whether there are such package versions using `composer why-not php 7.4` before deploying and downgrade them

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add a "dependency constraint" to `create-project`.

E.g. Something like an imaginary  `create-project symfony/skeleton --dep php: "^7"`.

What you could do is:

1. first `create-project`
2. Add the `config.platform` key to your `composer.json` adjusted to your server's version ([Docs.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform))
3. Run `composer update`

Either some packages will be downgraded if needed, or you'll get a message telling you that the new, target version is incompatible.

E.g. after doing a `create-project symfony/skeleton` and changing `config.platform.php` to `7.2`, on executing `composer update` I get:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

[image]